# LameUser trying - apache2 webserver authentication - IP range to access without pass prompt others with it

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ip, authentication, password

I have (maybe silly) question regarding the apache2 webserver and security - I am trying to archieve this: Users connecting from 192.168.1.24 not to be prompted for password and allowed Others asked for username and password if correct then connect. I am trying to do this for the whole directory /var/www

No matter whether I put the code into .htaccess file or in httpd.conf it doesn't work for me.

```
Order deny,allow 
Deny from all 
AuthName "PassRequest" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd 
Require valid-user 
Allow from 192.168.1.24 
Satisfy Any
```

If I try to connect to the page I am allowed from both the allowed IP or any other, If I remove the satisfy any line then I am prompted for password, if I remove the password too and try to connect from different IP I am NOT REFUSED ... is there some module that needs to be activated or why is the IP directive skipped ?

It needs to be put in every folder or /var/www/.htaccess is enough ? can I just put it in httpd.conf instead or not ??

I spend last 4 hours trying to google up why it is acting like that, Any help will be highly appreciated :-))

EDIT 1.11.2012: added Allow Override, applied to directory and moved to httpd.conf, no success, checked loaded modules, problem still persists

I added the AllowOverride directive (although there currently was no .htaccess in /var/www) and put everything to httpd.conf with directory of root ...

Here is what I currently have in httpd.conf

```
    <Directory />
AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from All
   Allow from 195.137.181.24
   Options Indexes
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "You are accessing outside of our network, Enter password!"
   AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user

Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

the list of loaded modules from apache2ctl -M:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 perl_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 python_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Authz_host module is there, so I don't see where else I could have done mistake. Still the problem is the same: when I access from IP 195.137.181.24 I am allowed and not asked for password, when I try to access from my cell phone through 3G with completely different IP I am still allowed and NOT PROMPTED for password :-(((

What am I doing wrong ? I have no more ideas what to try. Any more help or advices would be gratly appreciated. Mike

---

I added the AllowOverride directive (although there currently was no .htaccess in /var/www) and put everything to httpd.conf with directory of root ...

Here is what I currently have in httpd.conf

```
    <Directory />
AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from All
   Allow from 195.137.181.24
   Options Indexes
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "You are accessing outside of our network, Enter password!"
   AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user

Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

the list of loaded modules from apache2ctl -M:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 perl_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 python_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Authz_host module is there, so I don't see where else I could have done mistake.
Still the problem is the same: when I access from IP 195.137.181.24 I am allowed and not asked for password, when I try to access from my cell phone through 3G with completely different IP I am still allowed and NOT PROMPTED for password :-(((

---

Update 5.11.2012

I found it :-D

In apache2/sites-enabled was a hidden file overriding my directives on /var/www folder ... silly me not to think of it earlier :-)

Comment: As a starter you should format your question in some more readable way: the tools are there in the editor, use them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all / your configuration is correct and works as expected on my system.

Check the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive in your httpd.conf and if you did load the mod_authz_host module into apache...

To your other questions: you can put your configuration inside the [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) directive in the same way as you do in .htaccess - and it's even preferred.

Settings for each directory is inherited to all subdirectories, so to protect the root directory is enough.